# Custom menu not linking pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom menu created in wordpress. But the pages added using the custom menu is not linking correctly its defaulting to the homepage and not pointing to the page. though the url in the address bar is correct, but the page displayed is the home page.

I am not sure if its a problem with the theme coding? I am looking at how we can debug to find out where the problem is?

url : http://freedomformulapromotion.com/blog/

The menu's About, another post and nextpage are pages in wordpress, Hello world and help are posts. The post's links work fine the pages dont work.

Any suggestions on how to identify the problem would be of great help

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... found out what the problem was...
The theme didnt have a page.php, i copied the single.php and renamed it as page.php...
It worked  :)